# How to get admob banner shown in bottom true

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob, banner

I've made a app and I got the banner working, but I want the banner in the bottom. I have tried a lot but I cant get it to work. Hope someone can help me here.

This is the code in the main.xml, currently the Ad is shown in the center

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">




    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="Tanzverbot Soundboard" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">


     </FrameLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        />



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Need a screenshot to see what your screen looks like to help.

Comment: @ConnorT https://gyazo.com/b751fb07079e81f707ed3759cb5683cf

Comment: Your problem is that you are using `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`. Get rid of this line and this should work for you

Comment: Oh yes, thanks a lot

Comment: I posted it as a question so if you could accept it as the answer that would help people when they get stuck

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`. Get rid of this line and this should work for you.

Hope this helps!